# What is the big O when I subtract two sets?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

If I have two non-empty sets of equal lengths, B and A, what is the big O time to subtract B from A (B-A; length(B) == length(A))? I think it is either O(n) or O(1), but not sure which one.

Also, would this question be more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by subtraction you mean the set difference operator, if n=A.length, then this would take O(n^2) time. This is because for every element in A, you must compare it to every element in B to determine if the elements are the same and that element can be removed from B. In the worst case, the intersection of A and B is empty, so you will need to compare n elements from A against n elements from B, leading to a runtime of O(n^2).

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are subset of an ordered set, it can be done more efficiently. First, sort them. The whole thing becomes $O(n\log n)$, where $n=\lvert A\rvert$.

Comment: @Clement C true, I was just answering for the general case assuming we know nothing about the sets

Comment: If we're talking about something encoded in a computer, technically any set can be sorted by using the representation of its elements.